# Offline Face Recognition On Flutter

Tags: flutter, computer-vision, face-detection, firebase-mlkit, android-vision

I am trying to build a flutter app which will have two functionality.
1. Save face data 
2. Recognize face based on saved face data.

I want to do this offline. The possible solution I found on google is using Firebase ML Kit, but that requires a network connection.

Is there any way to do realtime face recognition without requiring a network connection?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase ML Kit's face detection API, an on-device API, works even when there’s no network connection. Note, the functionality offered is face detection, not face recognition.

Comment: Is it free of cost?